# Magento Connect extension installation error log

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager, algolia

I installed Algolia search on a staging version of my website and it worked wonderfully (after a bit of tweaking).  I've just tried to apply that to my production install, starting by installing the extension.

Unfortunately, when I do it it breaks search and breaks the admin console (search 500s and admin console puts up the "exception" screen).  It seems this is because the Algolia install didn't install all files.  E.g. (from exception.log):

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Algolia_Algoliasearch_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications' in /home/cluster-sites/5/y/yateley10kseries.kallisti.co.uk/public_html/app/Mage.php:595

and system.log:

> 2018-07-04T12:55:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/cluster-sites/5/y/yateley10kseries.kallisti.co.uk/public_html/includes/src/Algolia_Algoliasearch_Model_Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/cluster-sites/5/y/yateley10kseries.kallisti.co.uk/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

OK - so it's obvious the problem - incomplete install - but the little green Magento Connect install screen said it went fine...?  Is there a log of that somewhere I could use to debug?

Comment: Share the extension url?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/algolia-algoliasearch.html - though as I say, installed fine in my staging environment.  I just need to see what's happening behind the scenes to mean that the contents of /includes/src are not getting installed.